# Radiobuttonlist selecteditem is always null

Tags: selecteditem, radiobuttonlist

Quiz project, a question has a radiobuttonlist with either 2 items(T/F) or 4 items (a,b,c,d)
number of questions varies. Panel is used to show only one question at a time (show/hide).
after answering all questions user clicks on submit button and all answers should be saved in database. In code behind selecteditem is always null and value is always empty string.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtQuestion" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnItemDataBound="FormatDataListRow" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel id="panel" runat="server" BorderColor="#536895" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" style="display: none;" EnableViewState="true">
                <asp:Label id="lblQuestionDesc" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList id="rbl" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" >    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>                
</asp:DataList>
```

on submit click. I call a function that search the page for RBL I am able to see their correct ID's and list items but nothing is selected.

```
 string id;
       if     (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList"))
               {
                   if (c.ID != "rbl")
                   {
                    id = c.ID;
                    al.Add(id + "," + ((RadioButtonList)c).SelectedItem.Value); //SelectedValue);  //
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're populating the RadioButtonList on the page load -
 If so - make sure you surround your population of the RadioButtonList with an
 If/Then/Postback block:
 if not Page.IsPostBack then
 ' populate your RBL
 end if

eg:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadradiobuttonlist();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the submitted value like this:

```
this.Request.Form[((RadioButtonList)c).UniqueID]
```

During debugging you can always check what values you've got in `this.Request.Form` collection.